# Probability that a point lies in an uncertain convex hull

Tags: probability, convex-analysis

Given $n+1$ independent random vectors $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,\Sigma_i)$, where each $\mu_i \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ let $C$ denote the random region formed by taking the convex hull of a realization of the set of $X_i.$  For some known $z \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ what is $p(z \in C)$ as a function of $z, \mu_1, \dots,\mu_{n+1}, \Sigma_1, \dots, \Sigma_{n+1}?$

Comment: This seems pretty hard. It is computable via a Monte Carlo simulation, however. If you are only interested in the value numerically, I would recommend this.

Comment: With respect to what measure is $P(z\in C)$ calculated?

Comment: @Vossler I only know of the most basic notion: We say that a set has measure zero if for any $\epsilon > 0,$ we can find a countable
covering of $A$ by sets $\{S_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} $ such that $\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}  v(S_i)  \le \epsilon,$ where $v$ is the volume in $\mathbb{R}^n$, given by $v(S_i) = \int f_{S_i}$ and the characteristic function $f_{S_i}$ is defined as $f_{S_i} (x) = 1$ if $x \in S_i$ and zero otherwise.